# How to upgrade cordova-1.6.0 into cordova-3.5.1 for android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to upgrade cordova-1.6.0 into cordova-3.5.1 for android. But I did not found cordova-3.5.1.jar and cordova-3.5.1.js file. From where I will downlaod it. Also most the SO posts suggest some command line arguments but however I am using windows, so that doesnot work.

I am new to Cordova Kindly help me and suggest the right direction.

Comment: there's no more cordovaxxx.jar but a separate project named CordovaLib that's linked to the project and built with it. The same for cordova.js which is added automatically when you build the project (you just have to reference cordova.js in your html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to install latest cordova you should using there CLI, it is easy and much maintainable.

Also there is no issue in installing it on windows ( if you follow proper steps ).
Following are some pre-request which come to my mind.

- **Android sdk** : Make sure `sdk\platform-tools` and `sdk\tools` are in Global Environment Variables.
- **Ant** : Make sure ant is present in your system and is included Global Environment Variables.
- **NodeJs/NPM** : Make sure node/npm is installed in your system and is included Global Environment Variables.
- **GIT** : Make sure GIT is installed in your system and is included Global Environment Variables.

If all above are fine then you can use following command to install Cordova :

```
npm install -g cordova
```